# Placement of a package unit heat pump for my shop

Tags: electrical, hvac

I was wondering if I would benefit by locating my 3 ton package unit heat pump  closer to the load center. The ducting would be my only interference with it closer to the load center. The unit would also be in the sun during the hottest time of day.

If the unit is to be placed 50 feet on the other side of the shop, it will be in the shade during the hot part of day. The ducting will not interfere with anything. I just have to run 75 feet of 6ga wires instead of 20 feet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming 50 amps (which is probably high for a 3 ton heat pump), the voltage drop for copper 6ga is less than 0.5% at 20 feet, and less than 1.5% for 75 feet. Both of those are far less than the 3% allowed, so you're good.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Good to know that electrically I can put

Comment: The unit on either side.

Answer (score 3):

longneck's answer above is correct based on the wire and **if** you can do it, but doesn't really answer if you would **benefit** from doing it.

There are a number of reasons, but I wouldn't worry much about the shade. Unless the shade is significant in that it actually lowers the surrounding air temperature some, it's a pretty minor improvement. Secondly, you might have the shade in the summer when cooling the space, but (depending on where you are located) you will also have the shade in the winter when trying to heat it.

You can place the unit farther away and other than the ductwork, you are mainly looking at just a higher cost in getting the circuit there.

Take into account the other factors on locating the unit - like noise, space around it (for mowing and such), running the duct, etc. Locate it where convenient and it impacts you the least.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The cooling is the reason for install. South Georgia is where I am located and not much need for heat, although I will end up using it. I think I will make things easier and put it on the sunny side of the building. I did not think of the noise.  80 decibels is what it is rated at. Which makes me want to put it on the shady side. I have a 5-6 degree difference in temperature between the shady side and sunny side.

Comment: I ended up hanging a 5 ton bard unit with 15k heat strips. I split the service to the unit with 2 60 amp circuits one dedicated to the heat strips.  Keeping the shop between 64 and 76 all day has been running $35 - $85 . Better than I thought. Voltage drop is about 15 volts( heat strips on) but within the bard unit acceptable range.